# FLUTTER- How to use selectableDayPredicate: in CupertinoDatePicker() widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-cupertino, flutter-datetime-picker, flutter-date-range-picker

in Material Design using showDatePicker() widget , we can customize selectable date in particular day using selectableDayPredicate: argument. so i have a list contains some DateTime(), this list is the available date we can choose on the date picker. in materialDesign showDatePicker it will looks like this (black text is available date, grey is unavailable)

[image]

there is no problem using this widget, but when i want to make adaptive interface for ios device and change the style of the datePicker using CupertinoDatePicker, there is no argument that can change and customize the available date.

any way how to do that?